# Create new column iteratively by adding two columns and dropping the originals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'col_1':[1,1,1],'col_2':[1,1,1],'col_3':[2,2,2],'col_4':[2,2,2],'dummy':['a','b','c']})
```

which looks like

```
   id  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4 dummy
0   1      1      1      2      2     a
1   2      1      1      2      2     b
2   3      1      1      2      2     c
```

I want to add iteratively two consecutive column and create a new column and drop the original two columns

Expected output

```
   id  col_1+2  col_3+4 dummy
0   1        2        4     a
1   2        2        4     b
2   3        2        4     c
```

I was just trying

```
for i in range (1,dd.shape[1]-2,2):
    dd['col_'+str(i)+'+'+str(i+1)] = dd.iloc[:,i:i+1].sum(axis = 1)
dd.drop(['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4'],axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

which works but is there any better way using pandas functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's too complicated, you can simply add two rows by using the + operator

```
columns_to_add = [('col_1','col_2'), ('col_3','col_4')]
for cols in columns_to_add:
    col1, col2 = cols
    df[col1+'_plus_'+col2] = df[col1] + df[col2]
    df.drop([col1, col2], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for any number of columns to add iteratively two consecutive columns and create a new column and drop the original two.

```
col_list = dd.columns
for i in range (1,len(col_list)-2):
  dd[str(col_list[i]+'_'+col_list[i+1])] = dd[col_list[i]] + dd[col_list[i+1]]
dd.drop(col_list[1:-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
```